# When is a nullable not a nullable?

Tags: c#

Trying to understand the default behavior of GetValueOrDefault(). If I have a nullable property should GetValueOrDefault() return the underlying default value or the instantiated value of null...because that instantiated value (null) would be the value so we don't need to get a "default" value.

For example:

```
namespace Nullable_test
{
   public class AutoPropNullTest
   {
     public int? AutoValue { get; set; }
   }

   public class ManualPropNullTest
   {

      private int? i;

      public int? ManualValue
      {
        get
        {
            return i;
        }

        set
        {
            i = value;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

The above will instantiate with null values but calling ValueOrDefault will return zero.

```
        ManualPropNullTest x = new ManualPropNullTest();

        AutoPropNullTest y = new AutoPropNullTest();

        //x & y will inspect as null

        int? q = x.ManualValue.GetValueOrDefault();

        //q will result in zero
```

I understand this is a splitting hairs type question just trying to reconcile with what I think default should be and what reality is.

Thank You

Comment: `ValueOrDefaultValueForTheUnderlyingType` is too long to type.

Comment: Or even `ValueOrDefaultForTheUnderlyingValueType`

Comment: Yes, `GetValueOrDefault()` will return 0 - what did you expect it to do? Note that you can show exactly the same effect with a local variable - no need for  these properties...

Comment: "The GetValueOrDefault method returns a value even if the HasValue property is false (unlike the Value property, which throws an exception)."

Comment: @JonSkeet I expected it to return null...that is the value the class gave it when the class instantiated.

Comment: @user1278561: Did you read the documentation for `GetValueOrDefault()`? Given that you were calling it on a `Nullable<int>`, so it would return a value of type `int`, how could it have returned `null` anyway?

Comment: @user1278561: A specific instance can be null, the default value of the underlying generic type is a completely different thing, hence a separate method to get that value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Nullable<T>` type wraps a value type in a type that the compiler and run-time understand as a "nullable" type, in that it can be treated in certain contexts as if it could have a null value.

But note that the `null` value means the *absence* of a value, not some default value.

When you call `GetValueOrDefault()`, what you're asking for is the *non-nullable* value from the `Nullable<T>` value, or the *value type's* own default value if the `Nullable<T>` value is in fact "null".

In this scenario, you should expect the underlying default value. That's exactly what the method is intended to return. Note also that this is in fact an actual *value*, and so if assigned to yet another `Nullable<T>` variable, will be considered *non-null* (i.e. the value is present).

Comment: the definition of null is abscence a value...that is the explanation I was needing.

Answer (score 3):

The "default value" is *actually*:

> The type of the default value is the type argument of the current
>   Nullable object, and the value of the default value consists solely
>   of binary zeroes.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So to answer your question, its whatever the binary-zero value would be of the type argument.

Answer (score 1):

GetValueOrDefault returns default(T) if HasValue on the Nullable type is false. (The default(int) is 0)

Answer (score 0):

The default value for int (Int32) is 0. The int? (Nullable) instance doesn't have an integer value assigned so it returns default for an int which is 0.